# Creating a simple Linq to EF Query for a Many-To-Many relationship

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

I have Two Many-To-Many tables which I need to write a Entity Framework Linq query for. All I want to do is to retrieve any People from the "People" table who have a relation to the Company ID = 7.

Can someone give me an idea of what that would look like?

The tables look something like:

People, 
ID PK,
Title,
Forename,
Surname

People_Companies
PersonID PK,
CompanyID PK,

Companies
ID  PK,
CompanyNumber,
CompanyName,
CompanyType,

The SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT     People_Companies.PersonID, People_Companies.CompanyID,Companies.ID,Companies.CompanyNumber, Companies.CompanyName, 
                  Companies.CompanyType, People.ID AS Expr1, People.Title, People.Forename, People.Surname, People_Companies.PersonID AS Expr2, People_Companies.CompanyID AS Expr3, Companies.ID AS Expr4, Companies.CompanyNumber AS Expr5, Companies.CompanyName AS Expr6
FROM         People INNER JOIN
                  People_Companies ON People.ID = People_Companies.PersonID INNER JOIN
                  Companies ON People_Companies.CompanyID = Companies.ID
WHERE     (People_Companies.CompanyID = 7)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
var q = context.People.Where(p => p.Companies.Any(c => c.CompanyId == 7)).ToList();
```